# CLR error: 80004005

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Since yesterday a few of our console applications gives us the following error on our Windows Server 2012 R2.

[image]

We didn't install any updates or applications to the server. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to downloading and re-installing (or run in repair mode) the .NET Framework.

If this doesn't helps you out, try the following:

1. Go to c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\
2. Delete the directory called "Assembly"
3. After doing that, install .NET Framework again.